# Click away from :visible div to close it

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, visible

Ok, this question has been asked alot.. but i can't find any answer which fits my current project.

I am creating a drop down menu which is very similar to facebook settings dropdown.

It is fully functional except for closing when a user clicks away from the div.

I've tried a couple of things, but i can't seam to get it too work.

Here is the jquery..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#settings").hide();

    $("#settings_button").click(function(){
        $("#settings").toggle();

     if ($('#settings').is(":visible")){
        $('#settings_button').css({"background-Color":"darkred", "color":"red"});
        };
     if ($('#settings').is(":hidden")){
        $('#settings_button').css({"background-Color":"", "color":""});
        };
    });

});

$(document).click(function(e) {   
        if((e.target.id != 'settings_dropdown') && $('#settings_dropdown').is(":visible")) {
            $("#settings_dropdown").hide();   
        } 
});
```

and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/F3X6k/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide your dropdown menu systematically when a click occurs on the document, and simply stop event propagation when a click is performed on a element that doesn't hide it

Example :

```
$(document).on( "click", function( e) {  
     $( "#settings" ).hide();
});

$( "#settings" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do some stuff
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3X6k/6/)

Comment: Although I gave my answer below - this is my favorite solution for this question! Minimal code and very effective!

Comment: Best answer thanks. When closing the div this way, the jquery style wasn't disappearing.. so made a little amendment here too http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/F3X6k/9/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated Fiddle: [**http://jsfiddle.net/F3X6k/8/**](http://jsfiddle.net/F3X6k/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#settings").hide();

    $("#settings_button").click(function(){
        $("#settings").toggle();

     if ($('#settings').is(":visible")){
        $('#settings_button').css({"background-Color":"darkred", "color":"red"});
        };
     if ($('#settings').is(":hidden")){
        $('#settings_button').css({"background-Color":"", "color":""});
        };
    });

    $("body").click(function(e) {   

        var myTargEle = $(e.target);

        var test1 = myTargEle.parents("#settings").length;
        alert(test1);

        if(e.target.id != 'settings' && e.target.id != 'settings_button' && test1 != 1) {
            $("#settings").hide();   
        } 
    });

});
```